# Setting Authorisation on Mp3 Files for Streaming

Tags: apache, authentication, hosting, mp3, audio-streaming

I would like to host some mp3 files for playing via a basic html5 audio player on a webpage that requires a log in, but the mp3 cant be publicly accessible.

My first thought was to setup a subdomain and use basic auth so that I can pass the credentials in the url, but it turns out this doesnt work in chrome and a auth message pops up for the user asking for credentials.

Since then I've been trying a few methods, such as proxing the request via php or having php stream the audio for me, but I cant seem to get it to work. Regardless of the guide or tutorial I have found on the subject, I am left with a message from the browser saying the mime type is invalid. I've tried playing with the response headers and tweaking scripts or libs I have found, but i'm at a bit of a loss.

Any suggestions about how to achieve this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

There are two general ways to handle this.  Both have many specific implementations.

## Method 1: Validate the credentials for each media file request

It's identical to handling any other request to your application.  However you're doing your login authorization, handle your MP3s the same way.

## Method 2: Pre-sign URLs

This is a readily available option if you're using a CDN.  Your application generates URLs and signs them with a hash of the essential parts of the URL and a secret.  The CDN knows (or can otherwise validate) that the URL was signed with an authorized secret, and doesn't need to re-validate.  This is performant, and ensures a proper separation of duties between systems.  As a bonus, these URLs can be set up to work only for a few minutes.  It's like generating a password for each and every individual file that only works for one person (ideally), and only for a short period of time before automatically rotating to a new password.  Your application effectively gives out this password (the signature) every time it generates a URL.